# Question about chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have a general function of the form:

$f(zx,zy)$ where $x,y,z$ are variables, what is the partial derivative of function $f$ with respect to $z$ in this case?

Comment: By $zx$ here do you mean the product of $z$ and $x$?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you need an expression for $$\frac{d}{dz}f(zx,zy)?$$

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,y)$ where $x$ is a function of $z$ and y is also a function of $z$?

Comment: Yep! It is the product of z and x.

Comment: @user90831, do you mean yes to Mr Croutini's statement? Because then the answer is different.

Comment: Hi, sorry i was assuming that x,y,z are independent. But xz refers to the product of x and z here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that $x$,$y$ and $z$ are independent variables.

If so, the answer is quite simply $D_{1}f\cdot \frac{\partial (zx)}{\partial z} + D_{2}f\cdot \frac{\partial (zy)}{\partial z} = x\cdot D_{1} + y\cdot D_{2}$.